# Regex include optional group with repeated match all group

Tags: regex

So here's my quandary:

```
^.*System(.*)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?\.log
```

I need a regular expression that will match this optional group in parentheses (a date). *However*, since this group is optional, and the `.+` is "eager", the date group never participates in the match. So I am trying to match things like these:

```
/var/log/ws/SystemOut.appserver204.log
/var/log/ws/SystemOut.appserver204.2014-10-22.log
/var/log/ws/SystemErr.appserver208.log
/var/log/ws/SystemErr.appserver212.2014-11-12.log
```

However, the first group, `(.+)`, *always* takes everything up until the `.log`, resulting in the optional date group never participating in the match. If I don't make the group optional, I start including the date, but then two of those cases mentioned above don't get matched.

How can I do what I am trying to accomplish? 
(For reference purposes, I am working in Java.)

Comment: So the date needs to be returned, correct?

Comment: @Khanna111 not just the date, the whole thing must be matched, but if the date exists, it needs to be matched. If not, leave it out. hwnd hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) operator meaning it will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match. Use `*?` for a non-greedy match meaning "zero or more — preferably as few as possible".

```
^.*System.*?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?\.log
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/oV7yQ3/1)

Comment: Awesome. This is one of those things where it's not easy to do a Google search on how to make a regex catch all non greedy.

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*System.*\.(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)\.log$
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this sample](http://regexr.com/3a0v8). The regex `^.*System(.+?)\.?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?\.log` matches the text in Group 1 and the date in Group 2 (excluding the dot). A visualization:

[image: Regex visualization]